# Cypher query optimisation - Utilising known properties of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Setup:

Neo4j and Cypher version 2.2.0. 
I'm querying Neo4j as an in-memory instance in Eclipse created TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();. 
I'm using this approach as it seems faster than the embedded version and I assume it has the same functionality. 
My graph database is randomly generated programmatically with varying numbers of nodes.

Background:

I generate cypher queries automatically. These queries are used to try and identify a single 'target' node. I can limit the possible matches of the queries by using known 'node' properties. I only use a 'name' property in this case. If there is a known name for a node, I can use it to find the node id and use this in the start clause. As well as known names, I also know (for some nodes) if there are names known not to belong to a node. I specify this in the where clause.

The sorts of queries that I am running look like this...

```
START

nvari = node(5) 

MATCH

 (target:C5)-[:IN_LOCATION]->(nvara:LOCATION),
(nvara:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarb:LOCATION),
(nvara:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarc:LOCATION),
(nvard:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarc:LOCATION),
(nvard:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvare:LOCATION),
(nvare:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarf:LOCATION),
(nvarg:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarf:LOCATION),
(nvarg:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarh:LOCATION),
(nvari:C4)-[:IN_LOCATION]->(nvarg:LOCATION),
(nvarj:C2)-[:IN_LOCATION]->(nvarg:LOCATION),
(nvare:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvark:LOCATION),
(nvarm:C3)-[:IN_LOCATION]->(nvarg:LOCATION),

WHERE   

NOT(nvarj.Name IN ['nf']) AND NOT(nvarm.Name IN ['nb','nj'])  

RETURN DISTINCT target
```

Another way to think about this (if it helps), is that this is an isomorphism testing problem where we have some information about how nodes in a query and target graph correspond to each other based on restrictions on labels.

Question:

With regards to optimisation:

1. Would it help to include relation variables in the match clause? I took them out because the node variables are sufficient to distinguish between relationships but this might slow it down?
2. Should I restructure the match clause to have match/where couples including the where clauses from my previous example first? My expectation is that they can limit possible bindings early on. For example...

   START

   nvari = node(5)

   MATCH

   (nvarj:C2)-[:IN_LOCATION]->(nvarg:LOCATION)

   WHERE NOT(nvarj.Name IN ['nf'])

   MATCH

   (nvarm:C3)-[:IN_LOCATION]->(nvarg:LOCATION)

   WHERE NOT(nvarm.Name IN ['nb','nj'])

   MATCH

   (target:C5)-[:IN_LOCATION]->(nvara:LOCATION),
   (nvara:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarb:LOCATION),
   (nvara:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarc:LOCATION),
   (nvard:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarc:LOCATION),
   (nvard:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvare:LOCATION),
   (nvare:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarf:LOCATION),
   (nvarg:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarf:LOCATION),
   (nvarg:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvarh:LOCATION),
   (nvare:LOCATION)-[:CONNECTED]->(nvark:LOCATION)

   RETURN DISTINCT target

On the side:

3. (Less important but still an interest) If I make each relationship in a match clause an optional match except for relationships containing the target node, would cypher essentially be finding a maximum common sub-graph between the query and the graph data base with the constraint that the MCS contains the target node?

Thanks a lot in advance! I hope I have made my requirements clear but I appreciate that this is not a typical use-case for Neo4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think querying with node properties is almost always preferable to using relationship properties (if you had a choice), as that opens up the possibility that indexing can help speed up the query.

   *As an aside, I would avoid using the `IN` operator if the collection of possible values only has a single element. For example, this snippet: `NOT(nvarj.Name IN ['nf'])`, should be `(nvarj.Name <> 'nf')`. The current versions of Cypher might not use an index for the `IN` operator.*
2. Restructuring a query to eliminate undesirable bindings earlier is exactly what you *should* be doing.
3. First of all, you would need to keep using `MATCH` for at least the first relationship in your query (which binds `target`), or else your result would contain a lot of `null` rows -- not very useful.

   But, thinking clearly about this, if all the other relationships were placed in separate `OPTIONAl MATCH` clauses, you'd be essentially saying that you want a match even if *none* of the optional matches succeeded. Therefore, the logical equivalent would be:

   ```
   MATCH (target:C5)-[:IN_LOCATION]->(nvara:LOCATION)
   RETURN DISTINCT target
   ```

   I don't think this is a useful result.

Comment: 1. In that case, would chaining multiple inequalities with <> bet better than using NOT with IN? E.g. (nvarj.Name <> 'nf') AND (nvarj.Name <> 'ng') 
2. Great, good to know it matches my intuition. I assume this is done in order from the first match declared to the last?
3. Good point. I suppose what I really want is possible valuations for target ordered by how many of the optional match clauses were bound. I suppose I would have to use variables for relationships, return these relationships and create this order manually?